# CSOM WorkflowServicesManager

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-addin

Is it possible to start a Workflow from a Provider Hosted Add-in without impersonating a user:

- In 2013?
- In 2016?
- In 2019?

My goal is to control user access to a list and start a workflow.  I am using the Add-in to give all users the ability to add and item to a list; the list can only be viewed by Admins.  The list has a workflow that I want triggered when a new item is created.

Also, I cannot use a login and password in my environment; all access requires a smart card.

From an example I found on the Internet, I simplified it to get the minimum code needed to get the error.

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var workflowServicesManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(ctx, ctx.Web);
    ctx.Load(workflowServicesManager);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Requested Permissions:

```
  <AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
  </AppPermissionRequests>
```

Error:
[image]